# WinForm: Find if network connection is metered (network cost)

Tags: c#, winforms, networking

In a Universal Windows Platform application, there are APIs such as `GetInternetConnectionProfile()` to find out whether a network connection has a cost associated to it, i.e. metered connection.

Is there a way a WinForm desktop application can find out if the network connection with active internet is metered connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just call the provided UWP class ? Its quite possible from a non-UWP project. Just add the reference and use. There are some examples shown here;

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/

Comment: Yes. It works. Thanks. Now my concern is deployment of these UWP libraries with my setip. I'll figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Raymond Chen has a good blog post here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20221013-00/?p=107285

Use this NuGet package:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts" Version="10.0.17134.1000" />
```

And here's what's worked for me:

```
public static bool IsOnMeteredNetwork()
{
    var profile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    if (profile != null)
    {
        var cost = profile.GetConnectionCost();
        if (cost.NetworkCostType == Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkCostType.Unrestricted)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```